# Can't use method findOne() in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

My project is about a User-Manager web.

I'm a new in Spring and Java.

Here is my code:In the UserController

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/{name}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User showUser(@PathVariable("name") String name){
    return userService.findUser(name);
}
```

In the UserService:

```
 public User findUser(String name){
    return userRepository.findOne(name);
}
```

And in the Postman when I go to the link:http://localhost:8080/users/hunghip4 (hunghip4 is a user I created)

```
{
  "timestamp": 1460570912129,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
  "message": "Provided id of the wrong type for class     com.uet.dhqg.usermanage.model.User. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.uet.dhqg.usermanage.model.User. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String",
  "path": "/users/hunghip4"
}
```

The User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends HypermediaLinks {
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="pass")
private String pass;

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void serName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPass(){
    return pass;
}

public void serPass(String pass){
    this.pass = pass;
}

}
```

The UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,String>{
}
```

Comment: Add the code for the `User` class here.

Comment: We need the `UserRepository` definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `UserRepository` is defined as `CrudRepository<User,String>`. Where `User` is the type and `String` the type of the id. However your `User` class has an id field of the type `int` NOT of type `String`.

First fix your `UserRepository` to be a proper representation of your `User`.

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

Next create a method to find your `User` by name.

```
public User findByName(String name);
```

And call this from your controller instead of `findOne`. The `findOne` is used to find entities based on ID not on any random field of your entity.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception suggests, you are passing the user name to the findOne method. But as per the method signature in the Spring docs, the method findOne expects the ID which is an Integer as its argument. Pass the user ID instead of name.

Comment: I tried but it say "in the CrudRepository cannot be applied to (int) "

Comment: When you supply Integer ID to the findOne method, what is the exception you get? Please provide the full exception log.

Answer (score 0):

Change your repository definition to

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Integer>
```

Your User id data type is int, so your repository Id should be int too. with this replacement `findOne` method also accepts integer data type as `User` id is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of the above artifact to 1.4.0.RELEASE in pom file and 
     do maven update project.

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Update Pom.xml and import maven changes

Answer (score 0):

````
//Create a BookMarkRepsoitory extending the JpaRepo
```import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface BookMarkRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
}
```

then in your class to access one book or any value use this method
```
 @Override
                    public UserDetails loadBookBookname(String bookName)
                            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                        Optional<Book> book= readerRepository.findById(bookName);
                        if (book.isPresent()){
                            return book.get();
                        }
                        else return null;
                    }```
````

Answer (score -2):

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
```

It is helpful

Comment: Instead of just posting a code snippet the questioner should add, please consider adding an explanation of what went wrong, how to fix it and why the proposed solution fixes the problem.