# findOne method doesn't compile with two data sources (MySQL and MongoDB)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot (1.5.6) application in which is included a separate module with all the logic to persist information in a MySQL database, up to this point, all works fine. But nevertheless, there is a new requirement to persist some documents (json) in MongoDB, I have added the dependency on the Spring boot's build.gradle file:

compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb"

And, in the separate module these dependencies:

compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.8.2'
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.1.2.RELEASE'

When I try to build my project, a common exception occurs over all findOne methods from the classes that extends CrudRepository (MySQL):

error: cannot find symbol findOne

Even without any MongoRepository implemented.

Any idea/suggestion about this error?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613270/cant-use-method-findone-in-spring-boot

Comment: You are mixing different Spring Data versions, don't do that. You are using an incompatible Spring Data Mongo version for the version that is supported by Spring Boot 1.5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be you accidentally bumped up the spring-data version to a newer release, which added some breaking changes to the `Repository` interface.

The `findOne` method was refactored to `Optional<T> findById(ID primaryKey);`. You can check if this is the case by verifying weather the repository that complains about the `findOne` method exposes a `findById` method. Another way of checking this would be looking at the dependency tree.

Source: [spring-data-JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to all of you. Indeed, the problem was the mix of incompatible libraries. I added the correct versions and all works fine :)